# Building a dataframe in C++

Tags: c++, dataframe, pointers

I am trying to build a DataFrame in C++. I'm facing some problems, such as dealing with variable data type.

I am thinking in a DataFrame inspired by Pandas DataFrame (from python). So my design idea is:

1. Build an object 'Series' which is a vector of a fixed data type.
2. Build an object 'DataFrame' which will store a list of Series (this list can be variable).

The item 1. is just a regular vector. So, for instance, the user would call

Series.fill({1,2,3,4}) and it would store the vector {1,2,3,4} in some attribute of Series, say Series.data.

Problem 1. How I would make a class that understands {1,2,3,4} as a vector of 4 integers. Is it possible?

The next problem is:

About 2., I can see the DataFrame as a matrix of n columns and m rows, but the columns can have different data types.

I tried to design this as a vector of n pointers, where each pointer would point to a vector of dimension m with different data types.

I tried to do something like

```
vector<void*> columns(10)
```

and fill it with something like

```
columns[0] = (int*) malloc(8*sizeof(int))
```

But this does not work, if I try to fill the vector, like

```
(*columns[0])[0] = 5;
```

I get an error

`::value_type {aka void*}’ is not a pointer-to-object type
     (int *) (*a[0])[0] = 5;`

How can I do it properly? I still have other questions like, how would I append an undetermined number of Series into a DataFrame, but for now, just building a matrix with columns with different data types is a great start.

I know that I must keep track of the types of pointers inside my void vector but I can create a parallel list with all data types and make this an attribute of my class DataFrame.

Comment: Do not ever use `void *` in a C++ program. At least not until you no longer need to ask any questions on stackoverflow.com, and know C++ sufficiently well to use it correctly (which is almost "never").

Comment: The same almost applies to `malloc`. `columns[0] = (int*) malloc(8*sizeof(int));` could be a much less troublesome `columns[0] = new int[8];` Less typing, fewer places you could type something wrong, and you'll get an exception if `new` fails.

Answer (score 5):

Building a heterogeneous container (which a dataframe is supposed to be) in C++ is more complex than you think, because C++ is statically typed. It means you have to know all the types at compile time.
Your approach uses a vector of pointers (there are a few variations of this approach, which I am not going into). This approach is very inefficient, because pointers are pointing to all over the memory and trashing your cache locality. I do not recommend even attempting to implement such a dataframe because there is really no point to it.

Look at this implementation of DataFrame in C++: https://github.com/hosseinmoein/DataFrame. You might be able to just use it as is. Or get insight from it how to implement a true heterogeneous DataFrame. It uses a collection of static vectors in a hash table to implement a true heterogeneous container. It also uses contiguous memory space, so it avoids the pointer effect.

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR Version

Discard what you are doing.

Use `vector<vector<int>> columns;`. When you need a column, use `columns[index].data()` to get a pointer to the backing array from the `index`ed inner `vector` and pass that `int *` to whatever required the `void *`. The `int *` will be implicitly converted.

## Explanation

[Quoting cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Void_type)

> `void` - type with an empty set of values. It is an [incomplete type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/incomplete_type) that cannot be completed (consequently, objects of type void are disallowed). There are no [arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) of void, nor [references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) to void. However, [pointers to void](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void) and functions returning type void (procedures in other languages) are permitted.

Since void is incomplete, you can't have a `void`. `void*` needs to be cast back to the actual data type, `int*`, before it can be used for anything other than passing the anonymously typed pointer around. All receivers of the `void *` have to know what it really is to do anything with it other than pass it on.

Functions that require `void *` parameters will take any pointer you give them without any further effort on your part, so there is almost no need to make `void *` variables in C++. Almost all cases where you would need a `void *` are filled in with polymorphism or templates. The last time I used a `void *` in C++ was back when I wrote C++ as C with classes bolted on.

## The Error

Given

```
vector<void*> columns(10);
```

where each element will contain an array of `int`s, let's work through

```
(*columns[0])[0] = 5;
```

step by step to see what types we have and make sure thee types at each step are consistent

```
columns[0]
```

Gets the first element in the `vector`, a `void*`. So far so good.

```
*columns[0]
```

dereferences the `void*` at `columns[0]`. As covered in the preamble, this cannot be done. You cannot dereference a `void *` because that you have a value of type `void` This produces the reported *::value_type {aka void*}’ is not a pointer-to-object type* error message.

We could

```
*reinterpret_cast<int*>(columns[0])
```

to turn it into a pointer to `int`, something we can dereference and matches the initial type, and receive an `int`, specifically the first int in the array.

```
(*reinterpret_cast<int*>(columns[0]))[0]
```

will fail because you can't index an `int`. That would be like writing `42[0]`. This means the dereference is unnecessary.

The end result needs to look like

```
reinterpret_cast<int*>(columns[0])[0]
```

But don't do this. It is unnecessary and grossly over-complicated.